# Using object values for TypeScript typings in function signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

We've defined some enum values in a const in our codebase, like this:

```
const Templates = {
    NewMessageFromBot: 'new_message_from_bot,
    NewMessageFromHuman: 'new_message_from_human',
    NewUnreadNotification: 'new_unread_notification',
}
```

(Example is shortened intentionally, but does in fact contain almost 100 entries for our different HTML templates for messages.).

We want to use these names as typings for a function like

```
function getTemplateName(message: MessageDocument, templateName: Templates) { ... }
```

But of course we get `Templates' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)`

Is there any way to reuse the *Templates* object as a type, or do I need to refactor it to be an *Enum* or does anyone have any good suggestions? Thanks in advance!

I've tried searching for similar topics, by searching for "reuse objects as types in TypeScript" but it does in fact seem I need to do something advanced here, or just refactor.

```
function getTemplateName(message: MessageDocument, templateName: Templates) { ... }
```

Comment: `typeof Templates` will give you the type of any const value enjoy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String Enums, the solution would be:

```
enum Templates = {
    NewMessageFromBot = 'new_message_from_bot,
    NewMessageFromHuman = 'new_message_from_human',
    NewUnreadNotification = 'new_unread_notification',
}
```

You may use the Enum as type, and also get the string.

Here is some [info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) about enum, in case you want to take a look.